# How Could I Make Rails Work With Backbone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have finished CodeSchool's Anatomy of Backbone.js Course, and I try to use it with Rails.

But I don't know why it didn't work....

My Backbone.js Code:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        title: "",
        content: ""
    }
});

var PostList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/posts',
    model: PostModel
});


var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',
    template: _.template(
        '<h1>' + '<%= title %>' + '</h1>' + '<br />' +
        '<%= content %>'
    ),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    }
});


var PostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    addOne: function(post){
        var postView = new PostView({model: post});
        postView.render();
        this.$el.append(postView.el);
    },
render: function(){
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);

}
});
```

And I have a Pages#Controller(it only has a index method) and a Posts#Controller.

I pointed pages#index as root path. And pages#index view likes following :

```
<h1 id="heading">Index Posts</h1>

<div id="posts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var postModel = new PostModel();
    var postList = new PostList({model: postModel});
    postList.fetch();

    var postIndexView = new PostIndexView({collection: postList});

    postIndexView.render();
    $('#posts').html(postIndexView.el);

</script>
```

And Posts#Index likes this :

```
def index
    @posts  = Post.all

    render json: @posts
end
```

（a post Object has two attribute, one is title, one is content.）

And I saw the response from /posts path is this :

```
[{"id":3,"title":"hi","content":"hi","created_at":"2014-04-18T03:50:51.444Z","updated_at":"2014-04-18T03:50:51.444Z"},{"id":4,"title":"post2","content":"post2\r\n","created_at":"2014-04-18T04:07:20.550Z","updated_at":"2014-04-18T04:07:20.550Z"}]
```

But whenever I go to root_url with browser, nothing happens.

Could anyone help me... Thanks...

**updated:**

I missed one thing not mention, I saw following error :

Started GET "/assets/underscore-min.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-19 05:37:52 +0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/underscore-min.map"):

Started GET "/assets/backbone-min.map" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-19 05:37:52 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/backbone-min.map")

Comment: Did you include jQuery and Underscore before Backbone?

Comment: Is it just because `postList.fetch()` is an AJAX call and you're not listening to any events on `postList`? Try `postList.fetch({ reset: true })` and then listen for a `'reset'` event from `postList` before rendering.

Comment: I updated the content to include the error messages I saw. Why it disaplys this error?

Comment: Don't worry about the 404s for the sourcemaps. Is your controller being called? Is it returning the right things? Are you accounting for the async nature of your Backbone `fetch` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included backbone.js in your application.js file?

see this [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/timtyrrell/intro-to-backbonejs-with-rails) for more details.

Comment: Yes, but I directly download from Backbone.js' official website and include it into application.js.

Comment: have you seen the slideshow? I made a workaround using that slideshow.

Comment: OK, I will check that in free time.  But normally, although I directly download from official website, it should work, right?

Comment: the best way is to download it from github. Well it should work but sometimes your system do not meet the dependencies required.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing anything get rendered because the render function is executing BEFORE the fetch operation is complete. Javascript does not wait on async events to finish before moving to the next line of code. To fix this, you need to modify your view to call render() once a fetch operation is complete. When a collection or model is done being fetched they will trigger a 'sync' event that can be listened for by the views or containing objects. All you need to do is have the view listen for the collection's sync event and then call render. Place the following code in your view's initialization function to create this binding:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);
```

This code will listen to the 'sync' event on this.collection and then call this.render when it is triggered.

You can also remove the postIndexView.render(); from the pages#index view as well because it is not really doing anything.